# How can I change Microsoft account linked to my Mojang account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I accidentally linked my little brother's Microsoft account since he saved his on my pc, so that one auto-filled. But I want to change the Microsoft account because of this issue I am unable to go online. Now I can't do anything online with my friends and I was wondering if I could change the Microsoft account with another.

I am not willing to buy another account since I have 6 years of playtime on this account. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

[The Migration FAQ](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050865492-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Account-MIgration-FAQ) seems to hint at contacting [Mojang support](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/requests/new) with your Transaction ID (see [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360029977371-What-is-a-Transaction-ID-) on how to obtain it). As far as I know there is no way to reverse linking a Microsoft account, as the migation is permanent, so your best bet is probably Mojang support.

Comment: Thank you, ill try that.